# as3 - How to sort display objects that constantly switch depths?

Tags: actionscript-3, zbuffer

I have a 2.5D game (2D game that acts like a 3D game) where you constantly switch depths, where the player displays on top of an object when it walks in front of it and when it walks behind it, the object displays on top of the player. Like when the player's y is less than the object's y, the player would be going behind the object and vice versa.

I tried to use a code like this:

```
if (player.y < block.y)
{
    setChildIndex(block, numChildren - 5);
}
else if (player.y > block.y)
{
    setChildIndex(block, numChildren - 10);
}
```

However, I see if I do it this way with multiple times, I would need tons of codes and the display list would get mixed up and sort the wrong depths in the wrong orders. Would anyone please show an organized depth changer with minimal code?

Comment: use a z-index stack sorting, the same used to create the 3d depth effect using just 2d techniques, in other words assign to each object a `zIndex` and at regular intervals run a `z-sorter` routine which sorts display ibjects based on their z-index value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [z-index stack sorting](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/zsort/), (also refered as [`z-buffer`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) in the 3D graphics literature) the same [used to create the 3D depth effect using just 2D techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order).

In other words assign to each object a `zIndex` and at regular intervals (e.g `onEnterFrame` event) run a `zsort` routine which sorts (the order of) display objects based on their `zIndex` value. Or, alternatively, you can run `zsort` routine manualy each time a change of `zIndex` happens on objects.

Then in your code you simply assign `zIndex` values to display objects to simulate an object passing in-front or behind another object and `zsort` takes care of the rest.

A trick here is to have appropriate gaps (i.e not necessarily next `zIndex+1`) in the values of `zIndex` assigned on objects, so that objects can be placed between these gaps to simulate passing in front or behind other objects, **without** having to adjust more than one `zIndex` value each time, i.e you adjust **only one `zIndex`** value of the object passing in-front or behind another object, and not the `zIndex` of that other object.

The amount of gap between successive `zIndexes` can be estimated from the **maximum number of (other) objects which at any given time might be between these objects** (so for example, if, at maximum, `3` objects might at some time move between, in-front or behind any given object, then a gap value for successive `zIndexes` would be `3` so that all the objects can be accomodated)

here is a very simple `zsorter` routine which runs periodicaly `onEnterFrame` event and does the necessary depth sorting for you (from reference 1. below)

```
package {

 import flash.display.*;
 import flash.events.*;

 public class DepthSortSpace extends MovieClip {

  public function DepthSortSpace() {
   super();
   this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.addedToStage, false, 0, true );
  }

  private function addedToStage( e:Event ) {
   this.stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.enterFrame, false, 0, true );
  }

  private function sortDisplayList():void {
   var len:uint = numChildren;
   var i,j;
   for( i=0; i < len-1; i++ )
    for (j=i+1; j < len; j++)
     if ( getChildAt(i).y > getChildAt(j).y ) this.swapChildrenAt( i, j );
  }

  private function enterFrame(e:Event) {
   this.sortDisplayList();
  }

 }
}
```

The `zsorter` above is in-fact a `movieClip` which acts as a `scene` container, in that you add your display objects to the `zsorter` movieClip and this takes care to sort them accordingly, but one can just take the `zsort` routine and apply it to any `DisplayObjectContainer` or `Scene` object instance.

**Note**, the `zsorter` above uses a [`bubbleSort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) sorting algorithm, which has a `O(n^2)` complexity, but one can use another sorting algorithm (e.g [`mergeSort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) with `O(n lgn)` complexity)

examples and references

1. http://nephilim.blogspot.gr/2010/06/easy-depth-sorting-in-actionscript-3.html
2. http://www.actionscript.org/forums/actionscript-3-0-a/169035-sorting-technique.html
3. http://www.simppa.fi/blog/the-fastest-way-to-z-sort-and-handle-objects-in-as3/

Comment: That's actually really cool! Could you please explain what the super(); is supposed to do? Thanks.

Comment: `super()` calls the movieclip parent class constructor, since `zsorter` extends the movieclip class it makes sure the constructor of movieclip is also called (via the `super` method call)